# Ipad / iphone accesing image locally with safari / chrome

Tags: html, ipad, google-chrome, safari

Is there any file path or way to access the images store/save on ipads/iphones? What I want to do is build a presentation wich will run over safari/chrome and access the images locally, with this the presentations will work with/without internet connection. Is any other approach to make this presentation work with or without internet?

something like this would be great

```
 <img src="ipad://pic.jpg" />
```

Ps. I know Ipad/iphone hasn't have an file manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot access photos from the browser. This might have changed with more recent updates but I doubt it. You can use something like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) to make a native app in HTML5 that has access to system components like photos.